# function' object has no attribute 'agent

Tags: chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I am building a food ordering chatbot but while running the online_train.py I encountered the error and due to that I m not able to train my model.

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import logging

from rasa_core import utils, train, run
from rasa_core.training import interactive

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def train_agent():
    return train.train_dialogue_model(domain_file="./domain.yml",stories_file="./data/dialogue/stories.md", output_path="./models/dialogue/",policy_config="./policies.yml")
```

I expected the output to be chatbot interacting with the epochs running but I got this error 'function' object has no attribute 'agent'